# How to successfully create a directory in Phonegap APP?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm using `cordova-plugin-file` plugin in my `phonegap` app project to create a directory in my app's folder.

I need this folder created so later on I can download some Audio files in.

I tried this code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    //navigator.splashscreen.hide();


// device APIs are available
    function onDeviceReady() {

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onRequestFileSystemSuccess, null); 

function onRequestFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) { 
        var entry=fileSystem.root; 
        entry.getDirectory("example", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail); 
} 

function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) { 
     alert("Created dir "+dir.name); 
} 

function onGetDirectoryFail(error) { 
     alert("Error creating directory "+error.code); 
} 


}
```

---

When I run my APP, I get the success alert which is `alert("Created dir "+dir.name);`

However, when I look in my APP's folder on my mobile device (`com.testap.app`), I can only see 2 folders and they are both Empty. one folder is `Cache` and the other one is `Files`.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something or not!

Can someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.